# Will a Transformer work from a DC inverter's output?

Tags: dc, transformer, inverter

If so, is it ever more efficient to use an inverter into a transformer to dial down DC Voltage?

Comment: Can you give a bit more detail on what you're suggesting here? Should we assume your "DC inverter" is a DC-to-AC step-up inverter as used to power mains devices from DC battery power or similar?

Comment: Exactly. I'm just wondering if there are any cases where it is more efficient to invert DC power and then feed it into a transformer as opposed to using standard resistors.

Comment: Um, "standard resistors" are not, by themselves, a method of regulating a power supply. PLEASE explain more about what you're trying to achieve / imagining in your head in your question.

Answer (score 2):

If by "using standard resistors" you mean making a voltage divider to derive a lower DC voltage from a higher one, yes, there are much more efficient ways of doing [DC-DC conversion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DC-to-DC_converter).

Inverting and converting back to DC is probably unneccessarily wasteful compared to the alternatives though. What is this for? If it's for a low-power (ie: electronics) project, you can buy switching regulators on a single IC which are about 70 - 95% efficient. These are pretty cheap these days and you can find them easily on DigiKey.

For higher-power applications, you can either buy dedicated DC-DC converter modules, or you can delve into the world of power electronics and learn about converters such as [buck converters](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buck_converter) (step-down) and [boost converters](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boost_converter) (step-up). If you do so, bring your calculus textbook along for the ride.